# how to maintain scroll position of ListView when database data change

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am making chat view which contains plain and image messages..I am using ListView and costumised CursorAdapter .My problem is when anything change in database like updating seen ,sent or delivered status ListView just scroll position to bottom.how to keep position same.Thanks

Comment: Experiencing same issue with recyclerview too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by removing the following line from ListView attribute
 `android: transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"`